# How to make Putty more transparent (transfer more key combinations to the remote)?

Tags: putty

When I use Putty to log into some Unix/Linux machine, many key combinations are "swallowed". For example, if I start `showkey -a`, type `Ctrl-End` or `Ctrl-Tab` or `Ctrl-ö` then nothing at all seems to be transmitted. `Del` and `Shift-Del` both transmit the exact same key code.

I played around with the settings under Terminal - Keyboard / Features, but nothing changed. The effect happens consistently on any Windows machine (running Putty) and any Linux machine (connecting to).

Is there a way to tell Putty to send more key presses to the server? I do not actually care *which* code is sent for any particular key combination, as long as they are unique; my main interest is being able to use more keys in Emacs, which is notorious for making use of plenty of different combinations, and am able to configure the actual bindings in there if needed.

I can not use tools like ActiveHotKey to fiddle around on the client side; I cannot recompile the Putty binary, and I cannot replace the binary with somethign else. Whatever I do has to be done inside Putty (current version) or on the remote end (does the TERM setting help, maybe?).

EDIT: this question is meant as is. "How to make Putty...". Recommendations to not use Putty are not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 I suggest you install Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and just use Openssh in Bash instead of putty.